# Require(...) condition location in wrapped functions

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

If I'm wrapping functions, like below, does it make a difference whether I check the input argument in the private function or the external one? Will it save me gas cost to do it in the external one because it will revert the function the earliest?

```
contract Example {


    function wrapperForFunction(uint256 exampleArg) external {
        //require(...) check best here ?
        _function(exampleArg);
    }
    
    function _function(uint256 exampleArg) private {
        //require(...) check best here ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is additional code in `wrapperForFunction` *before* `_function` is called, it can save some gas when you call `require` sooner. If it's just a wrapper for `_function` and you don't do any additional stuff, the difference in gas is neglectible.

Using the following contract, the total transaction cost is 21422 gas according to Remix.

```
contract Example {
  function wrapperForFunction() public {
    _function();
  }
  
  function _function() private {
    require(false);
  }
}
```

When moving the `require` to the `wrapperForFunction` function, the transaction cost is 21407, a difference of 15 gas.